# How to fix function 'cv::matchTemplate'

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, captcha, opencv

I want to read the captcha characters as one string.

This is an example of the images I want to read:

!https://ibb.co/t2h3SS5

The code I am using:

```
    match = cv2.matchTemplate(img_symbol, image, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    if len(match):
        _, quality, _, location = cv2.minMaxLoc(match)
        if quality > 0.8:
            result.append({'x': location[0], 'symbol': ntpath.basename(symbol).replace('.png', '')})
result = sorted(result, key=lambda k: k['x'])
return ''.join([x['symbol'] for x in result])
```

I've got this errors:

---

error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     37 
     38 for img in IMAGES:
---> 39     print('{} -> {}'.format(img, guess_captcha(img)))

in guess_captcha(image)
     27         img_symbol = cv2.imread(symbol)
     28 
---> 29         match = cv2.matchTemplate(img_symbol, image, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
     30         if len(match):
     31             _, quality, _, location = cv2.minMaxLoc(match)

error: OpenCV(4.1.2) ..\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:1104: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate'

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV's error messages can be a bit cryptic. Here is the meaning of every part of the error message:

- `depth == CV_8U`: the function expected a 8 bit single channel image (one uint8 value per pixel e.g. grayscale, but not RGB which has 3 values per pixel)
- `depth == CV_32F`: the function expected a 32 bit single channel image (one float value per pixel)
- `type == _templ.type()`: both input images must have the same type (both CV_8U or CV_32F)
- `_img.dims() <= 2`: the image must have at most 2 dimension (no multi-channel image, e.g. RGB)